# Bootstrap 3 button icon with border on the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create bootstrap button with icon floated on the left and it has right border **fills the full height** of the button.

I have tried the following CSS:

```
a.btn.btn-xlg i {
    float: left;
    border-right: groove;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4%;
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
...
<a href="/job" class="btn btn-xlg btn-olive center-block"><i class="fox-job"></i>Jobs</a>
...
```

The following is a screen shot for what I have gotten:

[image]

#### Update

```
[class^="fox-"]:before, [class*=" fox-"]:before {
    font-family: "fox";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    speak: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    width: 1em;
    margin-right: .2em;
    text-align: center;
    /* opacity: .8; */
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: .2em;
    font-size: 140%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(255, 207, 118, 0.9);
}
```

Is there any way that allows the border to cover the full height of the button as shown in the screen shot?

By the way if there is, but it is not essential, any solution direction less would be better. i.e in the rtl documents it does not need modification to float the icon to the right instead of left.

### Update 2:

According to Ghassen Louhaichi answer, I have got that screen shot:
[image]

And I used the following CSS :

```
a.btn.btn-xlg i {
    float: left;
    border-right: groove;
    /* height: 100%; */
    display: inline-block;
    /* padding: 20px 16px; */
    height: 72px;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, remove the padding on you button

Comment: Please also include the CSS of your `fox-job` class.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi It is just icon font. However checkout the update.

Comment: @ProEvilz removing the `padding` disturb the button design!

Comment: @SaidbakR So then make up for it another way... your padding is creating the space between the border and the buttons top/bottom edge. E.G. Set a height instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a padding in the button that you either need to remove and place the contents of the button in the vertical center manually, or add the following CSS rules to your class to counter the effect of the padding using negative margin (you may have to play around with the value a bit until it looks right) :

```
a.btn.btn-xlg i {
    /* the other attributes... */

    /* set the icon height to the button height */
    height: 34px;
    /* pad the icon to be at the center instead of the top */
    padding: 9px 4%;
    /* adjust the negative margins to counter the padding effect */
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried what do you regard like the following: `height: 72px;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;` and it gives me the most desired result. However, there is very tinny space between the border top and bottom edges with the button's edges, however, it looks like good!
Thank you